# How to take automatic database backup in jsp

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I have a  jsp web application with MySQL database.

database is on windows platform

i want to take database backup automatically

how it is possible to take database backup from jsp/java page?

Comment: Where is database? On linux??

Comment: database is on windows

Comment: You mean retreiving data from database to display in JSP page through Java class ?

Comment: i want to take database backup

Comment: Take a look in [Simple CRUD Web Application in Jsp, Servlet, JSTL and MySQL](http://javaknowledge.info/?p=478)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: You would want to schedule a job in task scheduler to do this, not make a JSP page do it.