# How to take automatic database backup in java

Tags: jsp, jdbc

i want to take my sql db backup using java code.
i am using this code  this code ids giving following exception

Thanks

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

 class DbBackup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


          Process p = null;
            try {
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                p = runtime.exec("E:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -p'' --add-drop-database -B HighCourt -r " + "G:/JAVAWORK" + "1" + ".sql");

                int processComplete = p.waitFor();

                if (processComplete == 0) {

                    System.out.println("Backup created successfully!");

                } else {
             //       lblMessage.setText("Could not create the backup");
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Rather than posting a new question, it is a better idea to edit the [question you have asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087576/how-to-take-automatic-database-backup-in-jsp) and include the details there by editing it.

Comment: There is nothing automatic about having to run a program to take a backup. MySQL already has an automatic backup facility. Use it. Or just write a shell script. There is no need to write Java code.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime does not know where to look for mysqldump.

Provide a full path to it. `/usr/bin/mysqldump` or something. Depends on the OS.

Comment: Or add "/usr/bin/" to the path